# Перемещение элемента массива в начало

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, подвернулась такая задача переместить элемент массива в начало. Вроде сделал, но может есть более красивый способ переместить элемент в начало?

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(arr);
var removed = arr.splice(3, 1);
arr.unshift(removed[0]);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Что вы называете красивым? Короче? Универсальнее?

Comment: Красивым = короче. Может есть какой-то уже готовый специальный метод для перемещения по ключу в начало.

Comment: @Puvvl Как Вам такой вариант arr.unshift(...arr.splice(3,1)); ?

Comment: @Александр примерно вот так и думал) Этот вариант вообще идеальный. Спасибо!)

Comment: Посибо за хороший вопрос 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подойдет если элементов будет больше чем 1

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.unshift(...arr.splice(3,1));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно отсортировать массив, указав что нужное значение должно быть первее остальных.

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var value = 3;

arr.sort(function(x,y){ 
  return x == value ? -1 : y == value ? 1 : 0; 
});

console.log(arr);
```

Можно вырезать из масива нужны элемент и засунуть его в началу использованием 2ух [splice'ов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var index = 3;

arr.splice(0, 0, arr.splice(index, 1)[0]);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Хороший подход, но хотелось бы еще короче :)

Comment: Стандартом не гарантируется, что Array.sort() является стабильной сортировкой. Соответственно, в зависимости от используемого интерпретатора JS, может оказаться, что и другие элементы будут переставлены местами.

Comment: Вполне подошел вариант со `splice`. С `sort` что то не понятное происходит у меня, через раз добавляет, но спасибо!)

Comment: Посибо за ответ 

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(a);
var b = [a[3]].concat(a.slice(0, 3), a.slice(4))
console.log(b);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: У вас элемент продублировался в массиве

Comment: @Puvvl, ой.. исправил.